# How to modify this "make-matrix" function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Well, the flawed function is as follows:

```
(defun make-matrix (n)
  (make-array (n n) :initial-element 0))
```

I want to use functions like `(make-matrix 8)` to replace the longer `(make-array '(8 8) :initial-element 0)`, but CLISP says there is a fault in `(n n)`, because `n` is not a defined function.  How do I write this `make-matrix` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You try to use `(n n)`, but that is Lisp syntax for calling a function named `n` with an argument `n`.  You should invoke `make-array` like this:

```
(make-array (list n n) :initial-element 0)
```