# Pass arguments to make-array

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun makeAr(li co)
    (make-array '(li co)))
```

This is not working, it says that li and co are illegals arguments despite me calling this for example:

```
(make-array 3 3)
```

This simply doesn't work. Anyone knows why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an array with size received as arguments in a function in LISP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726593/how-to-make-an-array-with-size-received-as-arguments-in-a-function-in-lisp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify this "make-matrix" function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678906/how-to-modify-this-make-matrix-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make-array` takes the array dimensions in a list as its first argument. To create a two-dimensional array of three rows and three columns, you would evaluate `(make-array '(3 3))`.

The quote character denotes literals. If you say `'(li co)`, you have a list that consists of the symbols `li` and `co`. To actually get the *values* bound to these symbols, you need to form the list using the function `list`:

```
(defun make-ar (li co)
  (make-array (list li co))
```

Also note that camelCase is not idiomatic lisp; you should separate words in symbol names with dashes.