# How to create a multi-dimensional array in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to call **make-array** function with a list as parameter? For example:

```
(make-array '((length '("a" "b")) (length '("r" "8" "5"))))
```

return:

```
#<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: NUMBER datum: (LENGTH '(...
```

Even if I try to cast the result of **length** with the following command:

```
(coerce (length '(1)) 'number)
```

it works for one dimension array but not for two dimensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Is it possible to call make-array function with a list as parameter?*

Yes, in fact you always have to pass it a list *designator*, but it has to be a list (or list designator) of *integers*.  The list **'((length '("a" "b")) (length '("r" "8" "5"))))** has two lists as its elements, not integers.  E.g., if you do **(first '((length '("a" "b")) (length '("r" "8" "5")))))**, you get **(length '("a" "b"))**, not **2**.  You'd need to do **(make-array (list (length …) (length …)) …)** instead.

It's described pretty clearly in the documentation for **make-array** in the HyperSpec:

> ### Function [MAKE-ARRAY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ar.htm)
>
> #### Syntax:
>
> **make-array** *dimensions &key element-type initial-element initial-contents adjustable fill-pointer displaced-to
>   displaced-index-offset*
>
> => *new-array*
>
> #### Arguments and Values:
>
> *dimensions*—a designator for a list of valid array dimensions.

E.g., `(make-array '(2 2))` returns a 2 × 2 array. Or, if you need to dynamically compute the dimensions, just **list** them together.  E.g., `(make-array (list (length '(a b c)) (length '(d e))))` returns a 3 × 2 array.

Note that the argument is *designator* for a list.  The glossary entry says:

> [list designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/26_glo_l.htm#list_designator) n. a designator for a list of objects; that is, an
>   object that denotes a list and that is one of: a non-nil atom
>   (denoting a singleton list whose element is that non-nil atom) or a
>   proper list (denoting itself).

That means that when you do **(make-array 5)**, the **5** is actually acting as a designator for the *list* **(5)**.  You can really think of **make-array** always accepting a list as the first argument, but that in the case of a one-element list, you can just pass the single element instead, since it's unambiguous what you'd want.

### Related

These are related, but not quite duplicates, since they are about *how* to create a list to pass to **make-array**, whereas this question is about *whether* a list can be passed to **make-array**.

- [How to make an array with size received as arguments in a function in LISP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19726593/1281433)
- [How to modify this "make-matrix" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19678906/1281433)

Answer (score 4):

**Simple rule 1: if you quote it, it does not get evaluated.**

This is data, not code: `'((length '("a" "b")) (length '("r" "8" "5")))`.

Why? Because it is quoted.

**Simple rule 2: if you want to compute something, then write Lisp code, not literal data.**

```
(list 1 2) -> (1 2)

(list (length '(a b c)) (length '(1 2 3 4))) -> (3 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Addressing an unanswered aspect of the subject of the question: much like Common Lisp lists, multidimensional arrays also have a literal representation, which can be convenient in some situations.

- Lists

```
(list 'a 'b 'c)

;; is equivalent to

'(a b c)
```

- A vector (single dimensional array) is represented as `#[n](foo*)` -- `n`,optional, being the number of elements and `foo` being the items in the vector, e.g.

```
(vector 1 2 3 4)

;; is equivalent to

#4(1 2 3 4)

;; or

#(1 2 3 4)
```

- A 'proper' multidimensional array, i.e. an array larger than one dimension, is represented as: `#nA<sequence>` where `n` is the number of dimensions and `<sequence>` has a structure similar to a nested list, e.g.

```
(make-array '(2 3) :initial-contents '((a b c) (d e f)))

;; is equivalent to the following. Note, the 'inner most' array arrays must have the same number of objects, i.e. lisp won't auto-fill them with nil or anything else.

#2A((A B C) (D E F))
```

But you don't need to memorize that.  Like many other forms, the Lisp reader accepts as input whatever it printed as output of make-array. (Given some caveats that I won't go into, or rather will leave as an exercise for the reader!)